# VPN not connecting to a specific site

Tags: windows, vpn, tcp, udp

I've been using NordVPN for quite some time, but sometimes when the VPN is on certain websites become unreachable with a timeout error. For example, https://g1.globo.com is only accessible when the VPN is off. This happens from time to time with random websites or other services, like streaming or gaming.

Changing the VPN's country sometimes help, but not always. One thing I noticed is that it seems this problem happens only when I use the UDP protocol. TCP seems to be working fine, although way slower.

The company told me to use the commands below as an admin. It works sometimes, but not always:

```
ipconfig /release
ipconfig /flushdns
ipconfig /renew
netsh winsock reset
netsh interface ipv4 reset
netsh interface ipv6 reset
netsh winsock reset catalog
netsh int ipv4 reset reset.log
netsh int ipv6 reset reset.log
```

What is weird is that I can ping the website and get a positive feedback, although I can't access it with a browser. I've tried several ones - Edge, Chrome, IE, Firefox - but no luck. NordVPN says everything is fine with my connection. Do you guys think it's something to do with their server or can it be something local?

I'm running Windows 10.

Comment: If you're not experiencing these difficulties when the VPN is off then it's unlikely to be a local problem. Most likely NordVPN is overloaded every now and then or some websites deny connections from VPN providers, etc. If you're able to ping a website it does not necessary mean that you can connect to it since ping uses a different network protocol.

Comment: I think I've solved it. Instead of using the NordVPN native program, I'm using the generic OpenVPN one. So far, so good!

Comment: While you seemed to have solved it there's another possible factor---websites sometimes defend themselves against hostile users by blocking IPs.  If some black hat is using the same VPN exit node...

Comment: I thought about it too, Loren. However, using the same VPN server but with a different client seemed to have solved the problem. Perhaps the client was using a protocol that was blocked by the website or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the problem was with the NordVPN app. Now that I'm running OpenVPN one, things seem to be back to normal.